# How to call waitForConnection(PyObject[] args, String[] kws) of MonkeyRunner using Java

Tags: java, android, monkeyrunner

I want to call waitForConnection function of MonkeyRunner using Java.

I know that it can use `device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection();` by Jython, but it cannot be used using Java because of mismatching parameters.

[Official MonkeyRunner API](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/MonkeyRunner.html) just for old version of MonkeyRunner.
Parameters of waitForConnection are 'float timeout, string deviceId' in official API, but parameters of waitForConnection are 'PyObject[] args, String[] kws' in jar package of MonkeyRunner.

I try to some ways to call waitForConnection as below, but it raises NoSuchMethodException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strArray={"emulator-5554"};
    String serialNumber = "1.0";
    PyObject[] pyobj = { new PyFloat(15), new PyString(serialNumber) };
    MonkeyDevice device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(pyobj, strArray);
}
```

I have debugged it, it used reflection class in waitForConnection function. It means I should put `device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(pyobj, strArray);` into a function with parameters 'PyObject[] args, String[] kws' as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strArray={"emulator-5554"};
    String serialNumber = "1.0";
    PyObject[] pyobj = { new PyFloat(15), new PyString(serialNumber) };
    MonkeyDevice device = connection(pyobj, strArray);
}
public static MonkeyDevice connection(PyObject[] args, String[] kws) {
    MonkeyDevice device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(args, kws);
    return device;
}
```

But it raises NullPointerException.

I expect to connect monkeyrunner to emulator and return MonkeyDevice object.

I don't know how to call waitForConnection() after some tries and searching on Internet.

Please help to solve to problem or give some suggestion. I am confusing with mismatch official API with real parameters in jar.

Thanks.